# Available Share Extensions on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am looking for a way to integrate my app in the Sharepicker. I already found the regarding example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and the [Manifest documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_EXTENSIONSelement).

My Problem is, that I do not want to receive Pictures, but links or other things. Is there any place (that I did not find) where the possible extensions are listed?

Comment: May I ask who is the publisher of these other things? can you provide a sample?

Comment: I am not sure, what you mean. The information comes from MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** You can only act as a share provider for pictures. For everything else, you can give developers an [URI scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that they can associate with your app, therefore being able to call it later on if they decide to share something with you. This, however, will not be a system-wide sharing extension.

Comment: That was not the answer I was hoping for, but the one I expected... Thank you anyway.